# How do you fix the error: "Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.EditText', 'double'"?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
         Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    final EditText distanceTxt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.distanceTxt);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            float distance = Float.parseFloat(distanceTxt.getText().toString());
            float dec = distanceTxt * 7.9;
            float total= dec * 1;
            tv.setText(Float.toString(total));
```

That is my code and the error is basically when in type

```
distanceTxt * 7.9;
```

It says "Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'android.widget.EditText', 'double'".

I know the error might be obvious ,but honestly I can not seem to figure it out.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculate `distance`, but you multiply `distanceTxt`.

```
float dec = distance* 7.9;
```

Will work

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First you will use `distance` instead of `distanceTxt` then you will use `float dec = (float) (distance * 7.9)`it will work.

Comment: Thanks fro the explanation.

Comment: for* woops my bad.